# Magento 2: I want to add option in frontend to choose the Inc.vat or Excl.vat price

Tags: magento2

I want to provide the option to the customer for choose to show the price Inc. vat or Excl. Vat.
any idea about how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a new customer attribute and provide template for that in account section so customer can make selection.

After that, you could do a plugin on this class **Magento\Tax\Model\Config**::getPriceDisplayType(). For illustrative purposes, I use customer first name but it seems to work for catalog and product pages e.g. John will see excluding tax whereas everyone else will see the default setting (in this case - including tax).

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
  \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
) {
  $this->session = $session;
  $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

public function afterGetPriceDisplayType($subject, $result)
{
  try {
      $customerId = $this->session->getCustomerId();
      if (!empty($customerId)) {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        $customerFirstName = $customer->getFirstname();

        if ($customerFirstName == 'John') {
          return \Magento\Tax\Model\Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_EXCLUDING_TAX;
        }
      }
      return $result;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()));
  }
}
```